Why narrowing doesn't properly work in react component function?
I faced a problem with unions in react component. Below example of code seems broken, but I'm confused why such behaviour is happening.
type Props =
  | { value: string; onChange: (value: string) => void }
  | {
      value: Array<string>;
      onChange: (value: Array<string>) => void;
    };

const App = (props: Props) => {
  const func = () => {
    if (typeof props.value === 'string') {
      const val = props.value; // works fine
      const change = props.onChange; // still union - might contain both types of value
    }
  };

  return <div></div>
};


How to fix that and see only (e: string) => void in onChange callback?

You need a literal type to discriminate the union

@MatthieuRiegler - Really? string vs. Array<string> isn't sufficient? Edit: Wow, that really does do it: https://tsplay.dev/ND098N

It only narrows down the type of value, it doesn't discriminate.

You need a literal type to discriminate the union which value isn't.
type Props =
  | { value: string; onChange: (value: string) => void, type: 'foo' }
  | {
      value: Array<string>;
      onChange: (value: Array<string>) => void;
      type: 'bar',
    };

const App = (props: Props) => {
    if (props.type === 'foo') {
      const val = props.value; // string
      const change = props.onChange; // onChange: (value: string) => void
    }
};

Playground

I knew about the variant you provided, and it isn't the way. Do you know why it doesn't work with string type?

You'll find a great explanationg here : https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30506#issuecomment-474802840
